# TypeError: 'Statement' object is not iterable

Tags: python, chatterbot

I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 22, in <module>
    talk_to(chatbot)
  File "main.py", line 18, in talk_to
    trainer.train(response)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/chatterbot/trainers.py", line 81, in train
    for text in conversation:
TypeError: 'Statement' object is not iterable
```

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer
from chatterbot.trainers import ChatterBotCorpusTrainer
import chatterbot_corpus

chatbot = ChatBot("hi")

def talk_to(chatbot):

  keep_going = "yes"
  while keep_going == "yes":

    user_input = input("Type Here: ")
    response = chatbot.get_response(user_input)
    print(response)
    trainer = ListTrainer(chatbot) 

    trainer.train(response)
    if user_input == "quit":
       keep_going = "no" 

talk_to(chatbot)
```

Comment: There's a reason why it is called **List**Trainer.

Comment: The example expects you to pass a list to `trainer.train`: https://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html?highlight=ListTrainer#training-your-chat-bot

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a list of strings to `trainer.train`.

From the Chatterbot documentation for `ListTrainer`:
https://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html#chatterbot.trainers.ListTrainer

> ###### `chatterbot.trainers.ListTrainer(chatbot, **kwargs)` [[source](https://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/chatterbot/trainers.html#ListTrainer)]
>
> > Allows a chat bot to be trained using a **list of strings** where the list represents a conversation.
>
> For the training process, you will need to pass in a **list of statements** where the order of each statement is based on its placement in a given conversation.
>
> ```
> trainer.train([
>    "How are you?",
>    "I am good.",
>    "That is good to hear.",
>    "Thank you",
>    "You are welcome.",
> ])
> ```

The error comes from the [`.train` code](https://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/chatterbot/trainers.html#ListTrainer), which does an [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) on the input value:

```
def train(self, conversation):
    """
    Train the chat bot based on the provided list of
    statements that represents a single conversation.
    """
    ...

    for conversation_count, text in enumerate(conversation):
    ...
```

You were incorrectly passing a single `response` object, which is a [`Statement`](https://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/conversations.html#statements), and a `Statement` is how Chatterbot represents just *part of a conversation*.

You instead need to pass a **conversation**. I don't know what the loop is supposed to do or what your training algorithm is, but you need to be passing at least 2 strings, probably the user input and the `.text` string value of the `response`, and wrap them in a list.

Something like this:

```
trainer.train([user_input, response.text])
```